# Is set of {ln(2)} is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if set of $\left \{ ln(2) \right \}$ is closed, since ln(2) is transcendental number.

I am doubting about that and I want to confirm.

Comment: You mean in the standard topology on R?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, then yes - $\{x\}$ is closed for every $x \in \mathbb R$. To see this, let us show that $\mathbb R \setminus \{x \}$ is open: If $y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{x\}$, then $| x- y| > 0$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2}$. Then the $\epsilon$-Ball around $y$, $B_\epsilon(y)$ is contained in $\mathbb R \setminus \{x\}$. Thus every $y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{x\}$ is contained in an open set disjoint from $\{x\}$ which means that $\mathbb R \setminus \{x\}$ is open and thus $\{x\}$ is closed.

In particular, for $x= \ln(2)$, we get that $\{ln(2)\}$ is closed.

Comment: I really doubt this is the question that was asked. Consider the tag (set theory) and the mention of transcendental numbers...

Comment: @Najib Ok, fair enough. Let's say that we talk about set theory in the spirit of the tag at MSE. And let's assume that $\ln(2)$ is the real we all got introduced way back in school. Thus we're are left with a question about a singleton of reals which doesn't seem to be regarded as a code for some other set. What witchery is this? (Honestly, I can't think of any set theoretical question regarding $\{ \ln(2) \}$. Thus, I probably need an additional hint as to what OP's question actually is.)

Comment: Yes, I have no idea what OP is asking either, which is why I voted to close the question as unclear.

Comment: @Najib Oh, I thought you were teasing me :D